# Tips regarding how to create an Java Solitaire game

Tags: java, swing

I got some question regarding the approach to create an solitaire game in java.

What is the best way of handling the cards in Swing? How can I drag them, and what is the best way to snap them into their right positions?

Comment: Tip - if you play your cards right, you may find that someone has already implemented this for you :-)

Comment: I draw an card from the stack, it's ... CardLayout, omg how great =)

Comment: The best way to create a solitaire game in Java is probably *not* to try to make everything with Swing. On the contrary: use as few Swing as possible. One JFrame, a JLabel whose ImageIcon is a BufferedImage and you're good to go. Java game programmers typically do **not** use Swing: I know about Java 3D games, I know about Java mobile games, I know about Java 2D games... But I don't about Java Swing games ;)

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best way to snap them into
>   their right positions?

The [Overlap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) might help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

What would be the best approach for dragging multiple images? I've come as far as using Java2D to draw two images to a JPanel, but I'm only able to drag one of them. I'll attach my source code. The problem with my solution is that I need to repaint the entire window even though I'm just manipulating one element. Is it possible to handle objects of cards, instead of images of them? So when I move one card, I'll move the visual presentation of the object, instead of a image (as I do now.)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Java2d_MainPanel extends JPanel{
    private static BufferedImage img = new logic.GetBufferedImage().getImage();
    private JButton knapp = new JButton("Nytt bilde");
    private JButton knapp2 = new JButton("Nytt bilde2");
    private static BufferedImage img2 = new logic.GetBufferedImage().getImage2();
    //coordinates for image 1
    private int x1 = 0; 
    private int y1 = 0;
    //coordinates for image 2
    private int x2 = 50;
    private int y2 = 50;

public Java2d_MainPanel(){
    add(knapp);
    add(knapp2);
    knapp.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    knapp2.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler2());
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionHandler());
}

public void newImage(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource().equals(knapp)){
    img = new logic.GetBufferedImage().getImage();
    repaint();
    }
    else if(e.getSource().equals(knapp2)){
    img2 = new logic.GetBufferedImage().getImage2();
    repaint();
    }
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    newPaint(g2d);
}
public void newPaint(Graphics2D g2d){
    g2d.drawImage(img, x1, y1, null);
    g2d.drawImage(img2, x2, y2,null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rabbits");
    frame.add(new Java2d_MainPanel());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 640);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
class MouseMotionHandler extends MouseMotionAdapter {
    @Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

  x1 = e.getX()-(img.getWidth()/2);
  y1 = e.getY()-(img.getHeight()/2);
  repaint();
}
}
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        newImage(e);
    }

  }
 class ButtonHandler2 implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        newImage(e);
    }

 }
}
```